# I do not know why my css is not being applied to my html?

Tags: css

I have the css code below but it doesn't apply the css to html in general only to h1 and h3 i have used the same type of looking code before but it worked

```
html {
    text-align:center;
    border:25px dotted #ff5c33;
    background-color:#00b300;
    color:#ff5c33;
    font-family:Arial;
    }
h1 {
    background-color:#ff5c33;
    color:#00b300;
}
h2 {
    background-color:#ff5c33;
    color:#00b300;

}
```

html is as follows I could not find a error in it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Official Volleball</title>
<link href="VolleyB/CssforVB.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<h1>Official volleyball team score</h1>
<h3>Wins:1 Losses:0</h3>
<h2>Number of spikes by shawn</h2>
<h4>Spikes:3</h4>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well, where's your HTML? The problem could be that you do not have any HTML. Make is easier for us to volunteer our time to help you.

Comment: doubt you want to put a border around the html element,,,, more like the body....

Comment: @WesFoster ok i added that

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: @WesFoster to have my background of page one color with a border around, while my h1 and h2 elemants will stand out to the viewer in a different color background and text, and everything should be centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're applying styles to `html` that you appear to be wanting applied to `body`.

Change `html` to `body` in your CSS so that the styles apply to the correct element.

```
body { /* Change html to body */
  text-align:center;
  border:25px dotted #ff5c33;
  background-color:#00b300;
  color:#ff5c33;
  font-family:Arial;
}

h1 {
  background-color:#ff5c33;
  color:#00b300;
}

h2 {
  background-color:#ff5c33;
  color:#00b300;
}
```